# Plotweb with gradient of interaction colors in R

Tags: r, interaction, color-gradient

I am making a plot web and I would like to color the interaction links with a gradient going from the upper level color to the lower level color.
Result should look like this :

[image]

I tried many functions like colorRampPalette but it didn't give the wanted result. I spent the last few hours researching and trying methods but nothing worked.

Do you have an idea what I could try ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.